# return a value from an activity that is called by a popup window

Tags: android, popupwindow

I want to call an activity from a popup window, I could do it by using method startActivity(), next i want to pass a value from this activity to a field in the popup window

I am trying to pass value by using startActivityForResult(), But I cannot override the onActivityResult()

how can i do this, Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: can you paste your code that what you have done?

Comment: Thanks for your replies..  But my problem is I created a popup window extending "PopupWindow", Now i want to start another activity from this popup window and get a return value from the new activity, So I tried to using startActivityForResult(), but its not working because my popup window not extending Activity, it extends "PopupWindow".

Answer (score 1):

So whats the issue? do you want to know how to write a class for a pop window? then the below code might help. Edit it the way you want and write the `intent` for the next activity. Also you can get data by `getintent` and send data by `putextra` throughout activities in android.
public class ShowPopUp extends Activity {

```
PopupWindow popUp;
LinearLayout layout;
TextView tv;
LayoutParams params;
LinearLayout mainLayout;
Button but;
boolean click = true;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
    layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    but = new Button(this);
    but.setText("Click Me");
    but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (click) {
                popUp.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
                popUp.update(50, 50, 300, 80);
                click = false;
            } else {
                popUp.dismiss();
                click = true;
            }
        }

    });
    params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    tv.setText("Hi this is a sample text for popup window");
    layout.addView(tv, params);
    popUp.setContentView(layout);
    // popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
    mainLayout.addView(but, params);
    setContentView(mainLayout);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values to other Activities by using Bundles.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("someKey", 50);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then receive it in your "SomeActivity" class by doing:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras.containsKey("someKey")){
   int defaultValue = -1;
   Log.d("Magic!", "My bundled extra: " + extras.getInt("someKey", defaultValue)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create transparent activity with limited width and height instead of Popup dialog box. So that it will look like dialog box And then you can open another activity and pass values using `intent.putExtra()`

By following this way , you will also able to use `startActivityForResult()`
 and `onActivityResult()` .

```
public class PopupWindowActivity extends Activity {

PopupWindow popwindow;
Button btnpopupopener,btnOpenActicivt;
TextView tv_result;
final static int POPRESULTcode=1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup_window);

    btnpopupopener=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnpopupopen);
    btnpopupopener.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater inflator= (LayoutInflater)PopupWindowActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout vi=(LinearLayout)inflator.inflate(R.layout.layout_popup_content, null);
            btnOpenActicivt= (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.btnOpenActivity);
            tv_result=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_result);


            popwindow = new PopupWindow(vi, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popwindow.setContentView(vi);

            btnOpenActicivt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent in= new Intent(PopupWindowActivity.this, SampleResultActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(in, POPRESULTcode);

                }
            });

            popwindow.showAsDropDown(btnpopupopener);

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(resultCode){
    case POPRESULTcode:
            Log.i("Result"," Getting Message From Result Activity");

            tv_result.setText(data.getExtras().getString("resultstring"));
            popwindow.showAsDropDown(btnpopupopener);
        break;
    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_window, menu);
    return true;
}


public class SampleResultActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_result);

    Intent in= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PopupWindowActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("resultstring", "Sending Sample String as Data");
    setResult(1, in);
    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sample_result, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnpopupopen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Open Popup" />
```

popupWindow layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOpenActivity"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Go To next Activity Get Result back" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="View Result Here"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't use Activity instead of popup because am calling this popup from a fragment, also I want to put some objects to the popup class and want to invoke some methods in the caller fragment, thats why am using popup, Is there any other way to call an activity and get return value from a popup window